# Firebase chat not working when device date and time turnoff automatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am implemented firebase chat its working properly when my device date and time set automatically but when I turn off automatic date and time unable to fetch and receives messages from **firebase** console. Why this issue happening?

Firebase query's are not working when my device time and date set feature either set automatically off . I am using below code please check:

```
NSString * strGroupId = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@_%@",CURRENT_USER_ID,[userDetailDict valueForKey:@"user_id"]];
FIRDatabaseQuery * query1 = [[[_ref child:@"Message"] child:strGroupId]queryLimitedToLast:10];
_refHandle = [query1 observeEventType:FIRDataEventTypeValue withBlock:^(FIRDataSnapshot *snapshot) {}];
```

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)."

Comment: Hello Frank, Firebase query's are not working when my device time and date set feature either set automatically off . Iam using below code please check : NSString * strGroupId = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@_%@",CURRENT_USER_ID,[userDetailDict valueForKey:@"user_id"]];
    
    FIRDatabaseQuery * query1 = [[[_ref child:@"Message"] child:strGroupId]queryLimitedToLast:10];

    _refHandle = [query1 observeEventType:FIRDataEventTypeValue withBlock:^(FIRDataSnapshot *snapshot)
                  {}];

Comment: Please click the edit link under your question, and make sure it is formatted correctly. Code in comments is hard to read.

Comment: It's seem that Firebase refuse to work with any device with wrong date and time. I'm having the same issues like you and I see that your post has been almost 2 years. Have you found the solution for this?